# Multiple conditions within pagination with SQL interjection PHP

Tags: php, sql, pagination, xampp, href

In PHP, I'm trying to implement pagination that displays different results from a SQL database based off LIMIT. I know how to write pagination with multiple parameters but I'm unsure of how to code the application to recognize the second condition for the SQL interjection.

If you look at the code where it contains the `foreach` and the `href containing page_number and category_id` I need to get the pagination at the bottom to adhere to which category picked within the `foreach` to display the correct data. Also I couldn't figure out how to implement the pages without hardcoding within the `for loop`

This is the function for the SQL query page

```
function get_products_by_category($category_id, $pn) 
{
    global $db;

    $arithmetic = 8*($pn -1);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM products 
              WHERE products.categoryID = :category_id
              ORDER BY productID LIMIT $arithmetic, 8";
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(":category_id", $category_id);
    $statement->execute();
    $products = $statement->fetchAll();
    $statement->closeCursor();
    return $products;
}
```

Here's where it gets called

```
if ($action == 'list_products') 
{
    $category_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'category_id', 
            FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    if ($category_id == NULL || $category_id == FALSE) 
    {
            $category_id = 1;

    }

    $category_name = get_category_name($category_id);
    $categories = get_categories();
    $products = get_products_by_category($category_id, $pn);
    $products_amount = get_products_total($category_id);
    $total = count($products_amount);
    include('product_list.php');       

}
```

Here's the foreach and pagination

```
<?php 
    $pn;
    $current_category;
    $total_page = $total/8; 
    $remain = $total % 8;
    if($remain > 0)
    {
        $total_page = $total_page + 1;
    }
    ?>

    <aside>
        <!-- display a list of categories -->
        <h2>Categories</h2>
        <nav>
        <ul>    
        <?php foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>
            <li>

                <a href="?category_id=<?php echo $category['categoryID']; ?>">
                <?php echo $category['categoryName'];?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

for($i = 1; $i <= $total_page; $i++)
        {
        ?>
            <a href="?page_number= <?php echo $i; ?> & ?category_id= <?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?> </a> &nbsp;
        <?php
            if($i == 1)
            {
                $pn = 1;  
            }
            else if($i == 2)
            {
                $pn = 2;
            }
            else if($i == 3)
            {
                $pn = 3;
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
        <a href="?page_number=<?php echo $i; ?>&amp;category_id=<?php echo $category_id; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?> </a> &nbsp;
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry I meant to edit that. I've tried that as well but whenever you click on page 2 in any of the categories, it automatically goes back to category_id == 1.

Comment: Please try again with code from my previous post (I've edited it already)

Comment: That worked, but could you explain to me why it works, is there a special property in the &amp method that recognizes the variable that a regular & wouldn't?

Comment: No, the &amp; isn't a problem (it's html entity, You can read more on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML ).

The problem Was that in Your original code You didn't use proper variable ($i instead of $category_id) and SPACES in link :)